# Crashlytics Fabric.io deprecated

Tags: android, crashlytics-android, fabric.io

Does anyone know what the proper way to implement `Crash report` using `Firebase` in `Android` application?

I have read `Firebase crashlytics` doc in that mention implement `Fabric.io`. `Fabric.io` is deprecate and in there document mention removed `fabric.io` dependency.

`Firebase`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

[image]

`Fabric.io reference`
https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/sampleapp/index.html

[image]

Without `fabric.io` dependency I am getting below error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.`

Note:
Please compare the steps in both reference, I have go through all the links but didn't find the proper way that's why I am asking here.

I am sure no 1 go through the links, that's why getting down vote great. I have attached the Firebase and Fabric.io document steps screen

Comment: My problem is start as fresh integration without Fabric.io so I don't need to do migration

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the firebase link you posted?

Comment: It's simpler when you don't have to do the migration then.. Just follow the link you posted.. Only thing you have to do is create a project in console and place the `google-services.json` file in your local project(rest steps followed)..

Comment: @sanjeev you didn't understand the question. My question is whats the proper way as Firebase says integrate fabric.io and Fabric.io doc says don't

Comment: @Pratik They have moved everything from console but yet to completely remove it from `fabric.io`. A similar thing that's happening in Google is `GoogleAnalytics` getting migrated `FirebaseAnalytics`. While everything is migrated they are yet to remove it from Fabric

Answer (score 2):

Late post

Here is the solution, first of all remove all the fabric.io related reference and code.

In the main gradle.build project level

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.0'
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
  }
}
```

Next, in the build.gradle app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' // add this line at top
```

and in the dependency area

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2' // add this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to remove the Fabric SDK from your app and use the Firebase SDK, Follow the [Upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android)

> This guide describes how to upgrade to the new SDK from the Fabric Crashlytics SDK. It describes the changes that come with the new APIs, the reason for the changes, and how to update your code, if required.

[docs.fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/fabric-shutdown.html) you can get the following information, So I don't know why you have so many down votes, this is a legit question IMHO. Maybe because you didn't do this research yourself which I just did here.

> You can continue using the Fabric Crashlytics SDK in your apps until a deprecation date is announced. **Once the Fabric Crashlytics SDK deprecation date is announced you will need to upgrade to the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK.** Old versions of your app still using the Fabric Crashlytics SDK will not break once it’s deprecated, however they will no longer submit crash reports.

But it seems like it will just continue to work as per normal after this date until further notice. Just leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

According to the documentation in [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/overview.html),

> Crashlytics has been integrated into Firebase, with new Firebase-only
>   features. New apps should use Crashlytics in Firebase to get access to
>   the latest updates and features. Fabric Crashlytics and the Fabric
>   dashboard will be available until March 31, 2020 for existing users.

My guess is that, it might be - Let's call it grace period ;) up until every other user migrates it and they migrate every other **tool** from **Fabric.**

By the end of March 31, 2020 everything related to Fabric might be removed. Hope I answered what you were stating about.

Comment: I hope now you go through the link or refer my question again and compare the steps

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that the Google page omits the android tutorial in languages other than English. (it can happen by bug. It happened to me.)
Ok ... I'm not very experienced with Crashlytics, and looking to make the migration I came across exactly these links that you showed and I was also confused.
But as I understand it, Fabric Crashlytics was acquired and incorporated into Firebase, so the first tutorial is old, when there was a need for the Fabric library to implement Crashlytics in Firebase.
The second tutorial does not seem to want to specify which new libraries will be implemented.
The best tutorial I found is this:
Oficial:
https://firebase.google.cn/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#kotlin+ktx_5
or:
https://medium.com/@onkart10/migrating-from-fabric-to-firebase-crashlytics-e8819933c484

I hope it helps others.